# How to simplify this trace term?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite

I have the following trace term:

```
trace(Sk' Ck Sk)
```

where Sk is a KxM matrix and Ck is a KxK positive semidefinite matrix. 
I'm involving this trace term in a Matlab code and it seems to suffer when computing this term. 
How could I simplify it (if possible)?

Comment: Which is bigger, K or M?

Comment: K is far more smaller than M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, note that $\operatorname{trace}(AB) = \operatorname{trace}(BA)$, whenever both matrix multiplications are defined.

So, we can rewrite your expression as
$$
\operatorname{trace}(S_k' C_k S_k) = \operatorname{trace}(S_k S_k' C_k)
$$
Note that $S_k' C_k S_k$ is $M \times M$, whereas $S_k S_k' C_k$ is $K \times K$.

Comment: That's true, I did not considered to shift the matrices...  but it seems to make a lighter problem in Matlab . Thank you